# getting simplification type of simplify function in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I am heavily using simplify function in my project. It works well in most cases. However, what I want is  the simplification technique that simplify function itself apply to my input so that I can print it out.

I tried to examine the simplify function but it seemed complicated to me. What I am exactly looking for is one more return value from simplify or related function so that I can both get the simplified result and simplification operation.

```
expr = Sympify(r"(2x-2)/2))
simplified_expr = simplify(expr) # x-1 which is ok
simplification_method, simplified_expr = simplify_Iwant(expr) # I need this
```

So that I cant print something like "cancellation of common terms" in the above example.

Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: There is nothing like that in SymPy. And depending on the input an object might have its own rules for simplification. But the main tools are `expand` (and there are several keywords that it can use individually or together), `factor`, and `cancel`. The expression you gave automatically is simplified because the 2 divides each term to give `2*x/2 - 2/2 -> x - 1`

Comment: @smichr I am aware all of what u are saying. I am looking for some workaround or trick to obtain that.